# Dialog lost focus? Whole screen "greyed out"

Tags: android, dialog, focus

So the user is prompted for a filename and the file is saved to external storage. Once this is complete I call another method for saving to Dropbox. This creates another dialog; a simple "Yes/No" where the user can accept or decline saving to Dropbox.

When the file has saved to external storage the Dropbox dialog shows but the whole screen is greyed out, like it has lost focus. Tapping on the screen brings it back to normal and all the functionality is ok but it is annoying. Code and screenshot below.

```
   private void saveToSD(){

    //Build dialog etc

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    // Save file to phone and then...

            saveToDropbox();

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
        });

    builder.show();
}
```

And the `saveToDropbox();` method...

```
private void saveToDropbox(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    if (mDbxAcctMgr.hasLinkedAccount()){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Upload to Dropbox")
                .setMessage("Do you want to upload the file to Dropbox?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is when we would save to Dbx", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();

        builder.show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not linked to Dropbox", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `show` for an 'empty' `dialog` after calling `show` for the 'real' dialog. Try removing lines.-

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

and

```
builder.show();
```